# Removing datalist option from second input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-datalist

I have two HTML datalist inputs (for first and second language) that **can't be the same**. Instead of not accepting the form, I want the first option chosen to be removed dynamically from the second datalist but I can't make anything work with JQuery.
Any suggestions with React are also welcome.

Many thanks!

```html
<form autocomplete="on" method="POST">
 <input id="fLang" type="text" list="language" onchange="removeLang()" placeholder="First language">
  <input id="sLang" type="text" list="language" onchange="removeLang()" placeholder="Second language">
 <datalist id="language">
  <option value="Chinese">China</option>
  <option value="English">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Russian">Russia</option>
 </datalist>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `jQuery` by using two `datalist` elements and detecting the change in the inputs as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form autocomplete="on" method="POST">
        <input id="fLang" type="text" list="flanguage" placeholder="First language">
        <input id="sLang" type="text" list="slanguage" placeholder="Second language">
        <datalist id="flanguage">
            <option id="fChinese" value="Chinese">China</option>
            <option id="fEnglish" value="English">United Kingdom</option>
            <option id="fRussian" value="Russian">Russia</option>
        </datalist>
        <datalist id="slanguage">
            <option id="sChinese" value="Chinese">China</option>
            <option id="sEnglish" value="English">United Kingdom</option>
            <option id="sRussian" value="Russian">Russia</option>
        </datalist>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    var fRemovedItem;
    var sRemovedItem;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fLang').on('change', function () {
            let first = $('#fLang').val();
            if (first != '') {
                sRemovedItem = $(`#sLanguage option[value='${first}']`);
                sRemovedItem.remove();
            } else {
                let sDatalist = $("#slanguage");
                console.log(sDatalist);
                console.log(sRemovedItem);
                console.log(sDatalist.append(sRemovedItem));
            }
        });
        $('#sLang').on('change', function () {
            let second = $('#sLang').val();
            if (second != '') {
                fRemovedItem = $(`#fLanguage option[value='${second}']`);
                fRemovedItem.remove();
            } else {
                let fDatalist = $("#flanguage");
                console.log(fDatalist.append(fRemovedItem));
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

**UPDATE:** Removed items never go back if users remove the text in `fLang` or `sLang`. This situation was fixed with new code.